# Retrieve the document ids of a nested subcollection in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure in my Firebase Firestore:

[image: Firestore1]

[image: Firestore]

Is it possible to query just the document ids shown in the middle column of the second image? This is my current query, which seems to me the most logical way to do it. The console.log returns the success message, but the array is empty:

```
async function getListofPosts() {
    try{
        return await useFireStore
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(`${postId}`)
        .collection('chat')
        .get().then(res => {
            let theMessageList = [];
            res.forEach(doc => {
                theMessageList.push(doc.data(), doc.id )
            });
            setMessageList(theMessageList);
        });
    }
    catch {
        console.log('error on getListofPosts')
    }
    finally {
        console.log('getListofPosts worked')
    }
}
```

Any help very much appreciated.
Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was facing the same issue and implemented this solution:**

```
app.post('/read-whole-collection', async (req, res) => {
    fireStore.initializeApp({
        credential: fireStore.credential.cert(FS_OBJ)
    });

    const db = fireStore.firestore();
    const { fromTable } = req.body;
    try {
        const adminRef = await db.collection(fromTable).listDocuments();
        const data = adminRef.map((doc, index) => {
            return doc.id;
        });
        res.send({ length: data.length, data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({ message: 'read-whole-collection : Something went wrong in reading data', error: error });
        res.send({ message: 'read-whole-collection: Something went wrong in reading data', error: error });
    };
});
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "length": 2465,
    "data": [
        "165ee1c0-98fb-4dba-b813-1b7276d0105e",
        "1UserId",
        "1shubhamverma",
        "1test",
        "2FOAE482A55029DA11ED88A4BB9D819E45AB",
        "3e3f5174e14a2584f12aa9cceaad7a1c",
        "8ffa892a-4dbb-4ad3-8c24-481a6cc4aebc",
        "AAAA",
        "AAAATEST_USER_APP_RATING_1_15DEC_3",
        "APP_MIGRATION",
        "PENDING_ACTION_15DEC_2",
        "USER_10000",
        "20Dec_1",
        "22-11-21",
...
...
...
...
        "411ED86A8CD8A643E1B8D",
        "Users",
        "ea2c7316-7a8f-4066-a5fc-fb4e471aabd9",
        "null"
    ]
}
```

**Postman screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Related issue - [Firestore Cloud Function empty collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858327/firestore-cloud-function-empty-collection)

It seems like your documents under collections `chats` and `chat` are empty (*document IDs are shown in italics*). So to solve this you shall use `collectionGroup` query.

```
return await useFireStore
        .collectionGroup('chat')
        .get().then(res => {
            let theMessageList = [];
            res.forEach(doc => {
                theMessageList.push(doc.data(), doc.id )
            });
            setMessageList(theMessageList);
});
```

Before going with `collectionGroup` query, I recommend you to read this query and it's limitations from here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: Many thanks, Muthu. I didn't realise Firestore considers the documents empty, thanks for pointing that out. The code above still returns an empty array but I understand why now. I'll post the solution when I have it.

Comment: Great! yes, please update once after you find a solution. it will help the viewers!